# What is TOPLEVEL_BINDING in ruby?

Tags: ruby, binding

It doesn't equal the `binding` at the main thread, what is this toplevel scope? What does this scope differ from the `binding` at the main thread?

```
> ruby -e 'puts TOPLEVEL_BINDING === binding'
false
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fact is, `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` always refers to a predefined global instance of `Binding`, while `Kernel#binding` creates a new instance of `Binding` that encapsulates the current execution context every time. At top level, they both contain the same bindings, but they are not the same object and you cannot test their binding equality with `==` or `===`.

```rb
puts TOPLEVEL_BINDING
puts TOPLEVEL_BINDING
puts binding
puts binding
puts binding == binding

# =>
#<Binding:0x9769ea0>
#<Binding:0x9769ea0>
#<Binding:0x9941ea8>
#<Binding:0x9941e58>
false
```