# Why doesn't this binding works

Tags: ruby, binding, metaprogramming, erb

I have this code:

```
require 'erb'
ab = 2 + 2
class Greeter
  def self.render(template)

    ERB.new(template).result(TOPLEVEL_BINDING)
  end
end

p Greeter.render("Hi <%= ab %>")
```

for which I get `undefined local variable or method 'ab' for main:Object`. However, when I change it to `ab` to be an instance variable everything works fine:

```
@ab = 2 + 2
class Greeter
  def self.render(template)

    ERB.new(template).result(TOPLEVEL_BINDING)
  end
end

p Greeter.render("Hi <%= @ab %>") # Hi 4
```

As far as I understand, `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` includes all the bindings with the top level, and that includes the local variables as well. Why isn't `ab` captured as part of `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` then?

Comment: You should read more about [local variables in ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/localvars.html)

Answer (score 4):

That is not `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` who makes the result `Hi 4`:

```
@ab = 2 + 2
class Greeter
  def self.render(template)
    ERB.new(template).result # NO binding at all
  end
end

p Greeter.render("Hi <%= @ab %>") # Still "Hi 4"
```

Even more, `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` **is never updated** with new local variables:

```
TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variables
#⇒ [:title] # it’s pry-related bullshit
a = 3.14
TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variables
#⇒ [:title] # no trace of `a`
```

Good answer on [what `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17170781/2035262) .